# Golang chat using udp problems

Tags: go, udp

I'm developing a UDP chat using golang for my University work.
It's almost done, but I have some problems. When I run my server and try to connect to it the Server dont recognize a new connection, I need to press Enter twice to make it work. How can I resolve that ?

The source code is in: https://github.com/FranciscoJLucca/T1_LabRedes

Comment: Remove one of the two goroutines that read from stdin.

Comment: Your client Read and Write functions should take parameter type `*net.UDPConn`. In general, when a library only returns you a pointer to library struct like `*net.UDPConn`, you really shouldn't be dereferencing it 99% of the time.